# mysql create function mysql5.7

Tags: mysql

I have a function in mysql 5.5 that worked. I am now upgrading to 5.7 and it fails the import any help would be appreciated

```
CREATE FUNCTION `CLng`(`n` varchar(512)) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
  RETURN n;
END;
```

Thanks

Comment: it works https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=46b0f717a50866df4bbfb211c4dedf26  what is the complete error message

Comment: Are you using `delimiter`?: `delimiter // CREATE FUNCTION ... END// delimiter ;`.

Comment: Your function performs implicit datatype convertion only. This operation is SQL mode-dependent, and in general it is logically incorrect. *and it fails the import* This functoin performs none import... what do you tell about??